# What is overlaying shared memory?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, process

I am looking at someones code comments and in a function mapping shared memory with another process it mentios grabbing a pointer and "overlaying" the shared memory.

Is that a made up word or concept or is it something very specific. I can't seem to make sense of it looking at the code either.

Thank You.

Comment: I think it's a made up word. I've certainly never heard it.

Comment: I don't think it's a standard technical term. Could you share some more of the context you've found it in?

Comment: Nope, that Wikipedia article is describing ancient history.  Back when 64 kilobytes or 640 kilobytes was enough for everybody.  A severe limitation in writing code.  But nobody writes 2 gigabytes of code.  "Overlaying" here means mapping a structure at a specific address.  What's being pointed-to, not the pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing specific about it, nor is it a made up word.  It means simply that the code overwrites the shared memory.   [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_%28programming%29).  The Wiki entry goes on in detail about overlay programming techniques, which is a specific meaning, but the first sentence describes the general meaning of the word.  I've used it and heard it used many times.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the link, this really makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Well, overlay does have a pretty specific meaning, see e.g: [Wikipedia article on overlay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_%28programming%29).

However in the context you describe, it sounds like it's may just be a term used by the other developer to signify that you are using a memory location that is conceptually the same memory that being used within the other process.

If this doesn't clear it up, it might help to know a bit more about the applications involved; e.g. what's the memory supposed to be used for, etc.